# How to use PySpark's Imputer to replace missing values with -1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The title says it all. I know to how to replace missing values with mean or median using `setStrategy('mean')` but could not figure out how to replace with a constant (say -1). I am interested in using PySpark's Imputer if possible. Appreciate any help

Comment: Are you looking for to fill some missing values in a specific column with -1?

Comment: yes and I plan to use Imputer to do it

Comment: can you please check if the answer below helps you..

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this, assuming for column a and b you are trying replace null values as -1

```
df.fillna(-1, subset=['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I am looking for a solution using PySpark's Imputer if it exists